# An upbeat Riley riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

My prefix is from a united land
My infix, two joints, but not on your hand
My suffix is someone you meet day to day
Together fortunate, or so some would say

> The last line is not actually a direct reference to the answer, but is related to the answer in some way.

This puzzle involves homophones (I wanted to add a tag for it but no tag seems to exist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you

> BRITNEY SPEARS?

My prefix is from a united land

> A BRIT comes from the *United* Kingdom.

My infix, two joints, but not on your hand

> A KNEE is a joint, two of them are KNEES.

My suffix is someone you meet day to day

> You would meet your PEERS on a day to day basis.

Put these together and you get

> BRIT + KNEES + PEERS = BRITNEY SPEARS.

Together fortunate, or so some would say

> This might refer to her song *Lucky* from her 2000 album *Oops...I Did It Again*.

Comment: Correct answer, but you didn't get the last line.  Can you figure it out?  Hint: What's a synonym for someone who is fortunate?

Comment: @Ertai87 I think I got it now! Just was in the middle of an edit.

Comment: Yup, that's the correct answer.